# Direct Printing a pdf file in local drive from a web

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

I have an online web page and in this page there is a form with submit button. What I want is now to print a test.pdf file (always the same file) located in my local drive when I click the submit button. Is is possible to send this file to the printer installed in my local network by clicking the submit button on an online web page?

in other words:

- Web page is online and it is on a different server.
- Pdf file is located in my local drive.
- I want to write a code on my online web page that always send the same pdf file to the printer installed in local network!

If it is possible, can anyone explain please? I searched a lot on web but could not find what I want!

Comment: Searching on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]print+local+file) might help?

Answer (score 0):

The `PECL printer library` is for server-side printing. You have to have the printer connected to the server the script is running on.

If your clients need to do the printing, you cannot use it. You cannot do the `printer queueing` with JS alone. If you are restricted to using the browser only, best way to go about this would be loading out all the pages you want to print in one HTML page with proper CSS page breaks. But beware, there might be browser performance issues depending on the size of that one page.

Another thing you could do is convert that HTML internally to a PDF and then allow clients to print it. This doesn't allow queueing, but serves the purpose.